# Spark: Running multiple queries on multiple files, optimization

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.5.0.

I have a set of files on s3 containing json data in sequence file format, worth around 60GB. I have to fire around 40 queries on this dataset and store results back to s3.

1. All queries are select statements with a condition on same field. Eg. `select a,b,c from t where event_type='alpha'`, `select x,y,z from t where event_type='beta'` etc.
2. I am using an AWS EMR 5 node cluster with 2 core nodes and 2 task nodes.
3. There could be some fields missing in the input. Eg. `a` could be missing. So, the first query, which selects `a` would fail. To avoid this I have defined schemas for each `event_type`. So, for event_type `alpha`, the schema would be like `{"a": "", "b": "", c:"", event_type=""}`
4. Based on the schemas defined for each event, I'm creating a dataframe from input RDD for each event with the corresponding schema.

I'm using the following code:

```
JavaPairRDD<LongWritable,BytesWritable> inputRDD = jsc.sequenceFile(bucket, LongWritable.class, BytesWritable.class);
JavaRDD<String> events = inputRDD.map(
    new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable>, String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<LongWritable,BytesWritable> tuple) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String valueAsString = new String(tuple._2.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(valueAsString);
            JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(data.getString("payload"));
            return payload.toString();
        }
    }
);
events.cache();

for (String event_type: events_list) {
    String query = //read query from another s3 file event_type.query

    String jsonSchemaString = //read schema from another s3 file event_type.json
    List<String> jsonSchema = Arrays.asList(jsonSchemaString);
    JavaRDD<String> jsonSchemaRDD = jsc.parallelize(jsonSchema);
    DataFrame df_schema = sqlContext.read().option("header", "true").json(jsonSchemaRDD);
    StructType schema = df_schema.schema();

    DataFrame df_query = sqlContext.read().schema(schema).option("header", "true").json(events);
    df_query.registerTempTable(tableName);
    DataFrame df_results = sqlContext.sql(query);

    df_results.write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("s3n://some_location);
}
```

This code is very inefficient, it takes around 6-8 hours to run. How can I optimize my code?

- Should I try using HiveContext.
- I think the current code is taking multipe passes at the data, not sure though as I have cached the RDD? How can I do it in a single pass if that is so.

Comment: What's the size of your event RDD? You are iterating on 60g of data and crossing it with another Dataframe?

Comment: @eliasah: Input RDD is 60GB. I am not crossing, but creating a new DF for each event type, following the schema for that event.

Comment: There is some crucial information missing about the query you are firing here. Your approach suffers from many issues: 1. Iteration over 60g. 2. Creating a Dataframe for each event 3. Writing "each event" individually

Comment: @eliasah: I can deal with 2. How can I avoid 1 and 3?
I am writing each event separately as the columns would be different for each event type.